# Jinja2 templating options not working in test, but are fine when running server

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I receive the following error...

```
ERRORS:
?: (templates.E001) You have 'APP_DIRS': True in your TEMPLATES but also specify 'loaders' in OPTIONS. Either remove APP_DIRS or remove the 'loaders' option.
```

...when attempting to run any test suite, with Django 1.11 and its standard test runner.

`manage.py runserver`, however, works just fine.

I tracked the error back to the jinja2 templates. My django TEMPLATES setting looks like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jinja2')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'environment': 'mysite.jinja2.environment',
        },
    },
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'mysite.context_processors.app_rendering_ctx',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You'll see there's no `loaders` key in either of the `OPTIONS` dicts, so the error is seriously confusing.

Stripping out, it's nothing to do with the context processors or environments. It's related to the `jinja2` templating...

Removing the `APP_DIRS` key from the first entry lets the tests run:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jinja2')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            #stuff
        },
    },
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            #stuff
        },
    },
]
```

But now I can't find the `jinja2` templates in my app directories, so visiting the site gives `TemplateNotFound` errors (of course!).

Does the jinja2 templating engine dynamically attach a `loaders` key to its own options dict? And why does the test runner fail with this when the server runs happily?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tick this as selected answer, since it's a workaround not a solution... but others can get over this by manually adding the APP_DIRS they want to search into the DIRS key:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jinja2'), 
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'myapp', 'jinja2'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'myotherapp', 'jinja2')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            #stuff
        },
    },
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            #stuff
        },
    },
]
```

Of course, this is neither a generic solution nor easily replicated if you have many apps. For just a few its fine.